# Where does an IRepository interface belong?

Tags: design-patterns

In a typical 3 layered system, GUI->DOMAIN->DAL, where does the IRepository belong? Does it belong in the DOMAIN or the DAL. I don't know enough about orthogonality and service layers to know what the difference is.(edit)Allow me to clarify. Where(In what layer?) should the IRepository interface be defined? Also in what layer should the IRepository be implemented? Allow me to clarify even further...I am trying to blend Fowlers "Seperated Interface" with IRepository. My concern is enforcing dependancy rules. If the IRepository is defined in the DOMAIN, then the DAL package will have a dependancy on the DOMAIN. Else, if vice versa, the IRepository is defined in the DAL, then the DOMAIN will have a dependancy on the DAL. Again, where does the IRepository belong? This is my 3rd edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually, IRepository (or rather specific interfaces like IUserRepository) belongs to DOMAIN layer. Repository is specific to a DOMAIN layer and is intended to work with aggregate roots. Hence the location.
But implementation of IRepository belongs to DAL of course. You can then use IoC to glue everything together.

Comment: Does this mean that DAL layer will have a compile time dependency on DOMAIN layer? Doesn't this violate layered architecture constraint? (I assume DAL is part of infrastructure layer)

Comment: @THX-1138, there're two parts DAL actually consists of. One is indeed can be viewed as infrastructure (like ORMs), but since only DAL knows how to persist and retrieve your domain entities, there're usually various mappings, custom low-level queries, etc. So having a dependency on DOMAIN is actually normal. In simple cases you can make your DAL completely generic or configure everything via external files like xml and drop the actual dependency, but most real-life projects require special tuning. The important part about layers is to separate responsibilities.

Comment: @Kostassoid, By exposing DOMAIN layer to the DAL, you are also exposing your DOMAIN functionality to the DAL which DAL does not need to know

Comment: @devanalyst, as with many good things lately it's a matter of convention (CQRS, for example, is a nightmare for DDD purist). you have to take into consideration the costs associated with full DOMAIN isolation. i never saw anyone do it lately. so, please, provide an example of architecture allowing this to happen with reasonable efforts (SQL/NoSQL).

Answer (score 1):

Since repository deals with retrieving and persisting data, the correct layer will be the DAL.

Comment: \@boca, How will you pass data to DAL for saving ?

Comment: You should have a repository object in you bl. So lets say you are dealing with Customers then you can populate a customer object in your BL and then pass it to the repository for saving: customerRepository.Save(aCustomer). Does that help?

Comment: @boca Are you saying the object is in the BLL but the interface is in the DAL, and that's why the DAL can receive the object as an input parameter?

Answer (score 1):

I would have to say that belongs in the DAL (Data Access Layer).  A repository is exactly that... a repository for fetching and storing your objects.  I believe it's considered bad form to have any business logic at this level which belongs to the domain layers.  And it's pretty obvious to see it has nothing to do with the GUI layer.